# Directory Object Not Found - Active Directory - Inputting from CSV

Tags: powershell

hi there im trying to import user accounts from a CSV file to Active Directory but i've been trying for hours to no avail. Basically I have the CSV file i want to import. So I've been trying multiple powershell scripts and getting the same error

CSV contents:

```
GivenName,Surname,Name,SamAccountName,Path,userPrincipalName
Scooby,Doo,Scooby,Scooby,"OU=Vehicles,OU=Production,DC=csc,DC=local",scooby@csc.local
Shaggy,Rogers,Shaggy,Shaggy,"OU=Vehicles,OU=Production,DC=csc,DC=local",shaggy@csc.local
Fred,Jones,Fred,Fred,"OU=Weapons,OU=Production,DC=csc,DC=local",fred@csc.local
Daphne,Blake,Daphne,Daphne,"OU=Weapons,OU=Production,DC=csc,DC=local",daphne@csc.local
Velma,Dinkley,Velma,Velma,"OU=Weapons,OU=Production,DC=csc,DC=local",velma@csc.local
Pat,Pending,Pat,Pat,"OU=Biological,OU=Research,DC=csc,DC=local",pat@csc.local
Red,Max,Red,Red,"OU=Biological,OU=Research,DC=csc,DC=local",red@csc.local
Peneolope,Pitstop,Peneolope,Peneolope,"OU=Biological,OU=Research,DC=csc,DC=local",peneolope@csc.local
Peter,Perfect,Peter,Peter,"OU=Energy,OU=Research,DC=csc,DC=local",peter@csc.local
Rock,Slag,Rock,Rock,"OU=Energy,OU=Research,DC=csc,DC=local",rock@csc.local
Gravel,Slag,Gravel,Gravel,"OU=Energy,OU=Research,DC=csc,DC=local",gravel@csc.local
Luke,Bear,Luke,Luke,"OU=Energy,OU=Research,DC=csc,DC=local",luke@csc.local
Rufus,Ruffcut,Rufus,Rufus,"OU=Energy,OU=Research,DC=csc,DC=local",rufus@csc.local
Dick,Dastardly,Dick,Dick,"OU=Energy,OU=Research,DC=csc,DC=local",dick@csc.local
Rick,Sanchez,Rick,Rick,"OU=Board,OU=Management,DC=csc,DC=local",rick@csc.local
Morty,Smith,Morty,Morty,"OU=Board,OU=Management,DC=csc,DC=local",morty@csc.local
Beth,Smith,Beth,Beth,"OU=HR,OU=Management,DC=csc,DC=local",beth@csc.local
```

Powershell Script:

```
#Enter a path to your import CSV file
$ADUsers = Import-csv C:\scripts\csc.csv

foreach ($User in $ADUsers)
{

       $Username    = $User.SamAccountName
      $Password = $User.Password
       $Firstname   = $User.Name
       $Lastname    = $User.Surname
       $OU           =  $User.Path

       #Check if the user account already exists in AD
       if (Get-ADUser -F {SamAccountName -eq $Username})
       {
               #If user does exist, output a warning message
               Write-Warning "A user account $Username has already exist in Active Directory."
       }
       else
       {
              #If a user does not exist then create a new user account
          
        #Account will be created in the OU listed in the $OU variable in the CSV file; don’t forget to change the domain name in the"-UserPrincipalName" variable
              New-ADUser `
            -SamAccountName $Username `
            -UserPrincipalName "$Username@csc.local" `
            -Name "$Firstname $Lastname" `
            -GivenName $Firstname `
            -Surname $Lastname `
            -Enabled $True `
            -ChangePasswordAtLogon $True `
            -DisplayName "$Lastname, $Firstname" `
            -Path $OU `
            -AccountPassword $Password  `


       }
}
```

Output from powershell:

```
New-ADUser : Directory object not found
At C:\scripts\Add-NewUsers.ps1:24 char:25
+               New-ADUser <<<<  `
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (CN=Rick Sanchez...DC=csc,DC=local:String) [New-ADUser], ADIdentityN
   undException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Directory object not found,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.NewADUser
```

this error is repeated 7 times or so but the only thing different is the name (where is says ObjectNotFound(CN=Rick Sanchez..) different name for each error

Comment: Without any details about the CSV we’d all be guessing. I’d first recommend removing the back ticks, or at a very minimum ensure no space follows a backtick on a given line

Comment: @DougMaurer thanks i have added the contents of the CSV file

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this `try catch` block to your code, according to some googling this error is related to the OU where you want to create the new users not existing.

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

foreach ($User in $ADUsers)
{
    $Username = $User.SamAccountName
    $Password = $User.Password
    $Firstname = $User.Name
    $Lastname = $User.Surname
    $OU = $User.Path

    try
    {
        Get-ADOrganizationalUnit $OU    
    }
    catch
    {
        "Creating OU: $OU"
        $name, $path = $OU.Split(',',2)
        New-ADOrganizationalUnit -Name $name.Replace('OU=','') -Path $path
    }

    # Continue script here
}
```

---

Unrelated but, you might also want to consider start using [`splatting`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-7.2) on your code for obvious reasons:

```
$params = @{
    SamAccountName = $Username
    UserPrincipalName = "$Username@csc.local"
    Name = "$Firstname $Lastname"
    GivenName = $Firstname
    Surname = $Lastname
    Enabled = $True
    ChangePasswordAtLogon = $True
    DisplayName = "$Lastname, $Firstname"
    Path = $OU
    AccountPassword = $Password
}
New-ADUser @params
```